# How to Run SSIS package from cmd prompt or powershell and its dependecies

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis-2012

I have Visual studio 2017 installed with Data tools. I'm able to opend dtsx package from visual studio and execute (Both from run button and right click the file from solution explorer and click execute).

Now I want to automate the execution of package and scheduled. So I tried to run this package using DTExec.exe via command prompt first but getting lot of errors

i.e.

> To Run a SSIS Package outside of SQL Server Data tools you must
> install Standard edition of Integration Services or higher
>
> There was an exception while loading script task from
> xml.System.IO.FileNotFoundException. Could not load filename
> "Microsoft.visualStudio.tools.Application", version=14.0.0.0,

Can someone help me how to execute the SSIS pacakge in command prompt or powershell and what are the components or installation required?

How does the visual studio executes without any additional thing can I do the same thing via command prompt?

Comment: *"what are the components or installation required?"* It tells you in the error: *"To Run a SSIS Package outside of SQL Server Data tools you must install Standard edition of Integration Services or higher"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone help me how to execute the SSIS pacakge in command prompt or powershell and what are the components or installation required?

The error message told you

> To Run a SSIS Package outside of SQL Server Data tools you must
> install Standard edition of Integration Services or higher

Visual Studio only enables development and interactive execution of SSIS package.  Running packages from the command prompt requires a licensed installation of SQL Server Integration Services.